# Apex replay debugger cannot replay debug log from Browser application

Tags: vs-code, apex-replay-debugger

I try using Apex Replay Debugger. I have successfully setup them all. With a log that's generated from Apex unit test, I can debug it in VS code. I can use breakpoints to pause the replaying.
However, when I do somethings on my org via browser, capturing the log, the replay won't paused at breakpoint.
The below capture is taken from Developer Console.
[image]
**UPDATE:**
The log level of them are both same: APEX_CODE,FINEST and VISUALFORCE,FINER

full log level

```
APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,FINER;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
```

I also notice the API version in those files are different, quite not sure it's a problem or not. The browser generates the file with API version 52.0, the Apex Unit test generates version 54.0.

Comment: The debug log levels are extremely important in getting the replay debugger to work. Please [edit] your question to include the log level settings that you're using.

Comment: Since it is visualforce remoting -- it mean it is stateless, so one of the approaches could be to catch parameters from browser console, and then execute it from developer console or any other tools.

Comment: @kurunve I have seen the guide about Replay Debugger here: https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/replay-debugger . It looks same scenario but they can debug them.